# execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to make an Alias using AppleScript. I am using Mac OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks).

```
sato ~ $ ll /Users/sato/src/test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 sato staff 18410 Jun 13 10:36 /Users/sato/src/test.txt
sato ~ $ ll dst/
total 0
sato ~ :( $ osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/Users/sato/src/test.txt" at POSIX file "/Users/sato/dst"'
29:121: execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
sato ~ :( $ osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/Users/sato/src/test.txt" at POSIX file "/Users/sato/dst/"'
29:122: execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
sato ~ :( $ osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to make alias file to POSIX file "/Users/sato/src/test.txt" at POSIX file "/Users/sato/dst/link"'
29:126: execution error: Finder got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I do it in command line

Comment: sato, I tested and tested and the script runs for me. The "app isn't running" is weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine on my computer. 
I think maybe you can try these things:

1. Try to relaunch the Finder;
2. Try to relaunch the Applescript Editor;
3. Try to restart your computer.

I've encountered similar problems.

Comment: +1; the error does appear to be unusual - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19974198/45375