# Accessing Contacts in AppleScriptObjC: "Application isn't running" error

Tags: xcode, contacts, sandbox, applescript-objc

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set allPeople to every person
end tell
```

When my program reaches this part of the code, it crashes with the error "Contacts got an error: Application isn't running (-600)." It's definitely running. I have the Contacts box checked in the App Sandbox menu of Xcode, and I granted permission for my app to access Contacts when I was prompted. If I turn off the sandbox, the program works without issue.

I've also tried running `tccutil reset AddressBook` in Terminal to reset privacy preferences for Contacts, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: You likely need to set up an entitlement to access Contacts...

Comment: I do have one set up. That is what I meant by "I have the Contacts box checked in the App Sandbox menu," but sorry if my wording was confusing. In the entitlements file, I see: `com.apple.security.personal-information.addressbook` with a value of YES.

It's weird that the error says the application isn't running, instead of something to do with privileges. But I do know that turning the sandbox off allows it to work properly.

Comment: The entitlements you have is correct. The error message is listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html). I would recommend a reboot, and then try your sandboxed app again. Also see this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19974198/499581

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks. I will also try it on a different computer. Stay tuned...

Comment: Just an update, this issue still occurs after a restart, and also occurs when I try to run the app on another Mac. Per your links, it looks like error -600 is an OS X error, so perhaps I just need to report this to Apple... sigh, then it will probably take ages for them to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend reporting it to Apple.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to mention, was that it might be worth trying "Tell application Contacts" and on the next line "activate"... or something along those lines.

Comment: I was able to get around this by adding a temporary exception for Apple Events and adding the UTI `com.apple.AddressBook`. Now it works OK. I'll use this until Apple can fix the issue.