# Starting gitk on macOS gives an error application is not running

Tags: git

When I'm loading gitk I get an error ->

```
Error in startup script: 58:102: execution error: System Events got an error: Application isn’t running. (-600)
    while executing
"exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes whose unix id is %d to true
        end te..."
    invoked from within
"if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "aqua"} {
    exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes ..."
    (file "/usr/local/bin/gitk" line 12212)
```

My git version is 2.17.1 and my mac os version is 10.13.6.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you have XQuartz installed (it's been a long time since I did so I have forgotten how to do it and/or check for it).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is relevant information about this in an older issue: [Applescript fails with error (-600) when launched over ssh on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957268/applescript-fails-with-error-600-when-launched-over-ssh-on-mavericks)

People has reported to solved this by either restarting the machine or killing "System Events".

```
$ kill -9 $(pgrep "System Events")
```

Comment: Worked with `git 2.3.5` and `High Sierra 10.13.6`. Thanks.

Comment: i come back to this answer every month :-)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution did not work for me. The pgrep came back empty, so I got a usage error for kill. This is because System Events wasn't running at all! A great mystery!

To start System Events if it's not running:

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/System\ Events.app/
```

Now `gitk` works as expected.