Error 600 occurs when calling AppleScript from Swift
I am a beginner in swift development with Xcode.
I want to call the following AppleScript from swift.
tell application "TextEdit"
    if (count of documents) > 0 then
        return name of front document
    else
        return "No document open"
    end if
end tell

This AppleScript has been tested in the Script Editor and can get the name of the open document.
I wrote the following swift code and tried to run that AppleScript.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var documentName: String = "No document open"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current Document:")
                .font(.headline)
            Text(documentName)
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            Button("Refresh") {
                getDocumentName()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func getDocumentName() {
        print("Bundle identifier: \(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "Not available")")
        print("App name: \(Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[kCFBundleNameKey as String] as? String ?? "Not available")")
        let script = """
        tell application "TextEdit"
            if (count of documents) > 0 then
                return name of front document
            else
                return "No document open"
            end if
        end tell
        """
        
        var error: NSDictionary?
            if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
                let result = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
                if error == nil {
                    documentName = result.stringValue ?? "Unable to get document name"
                } else {
                    documentName = "Error: \(error?.description ?? "Unknown error occurred")"
                    print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
                }
            } else {
                documentName = "Failed to create AppleScript"
            }
    }
}

Here is my Info.plist.
<dict>
    <key>NSAppleEventUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This App needs to communicate.</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
    <string>com.apple.TextEdit</string>
</dict>

About Signing & Capabilities
App Sandbox

Network ✅ Incoming Connections
File Access Type
User Selected File Read/Write
Hardened Runtime ✅ Apple Events

OS is Sonoma 14.6.1, Xcode version is 15.4.
The problem is that when I launch the app, then that error occured:
Error: Optional({
NSAppleScriptErrorAppName = TextEdit;
NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Application isn\\U2019t running.";
NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "TextEdit got an error: Application isn\\U2019t running.";
NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-600";
NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {36, 18}";
})

Also, button does not display a pop-up asking for authorization, and the same error occurs as above.
Is there a problem with Info.plist or settings?
Thanks,
I have confirmed that the short script
tell application "TextEdit" to return running
can be run from Swift．

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900167/1801544 ? I haven't tried, but according to this answer the plist format is wrong

This question is similar to: My applescript doesn't work any more when I upgrade my OS X to 10.9. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
